# Solve these two limits $\lim_{x\to 1} \left(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{2}{x^2-1}\right)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{|x|}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Can someone help me to solve this limit please? 
it always lead to A/0 such that A is any number belong to R.

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \left( \frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{2}{x^2-1} \right)$$

also the left side part lead to same answer:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{|x|} \right)$$

Comment: Combine the terms to get $\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: yes i do , but combining didnt lead me to that can u show me how u did that pls ?

Comment: Notice that when $x<0, \frac{2}{x}-\frac{2}{|x|}=\frac{4}{x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that $$\frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{2}{x^2-1} = \frac{1}{x-1} \left(1 - \frac{2}{x+1}\right) = \frac{1}{x-1} \left(\frac{x+1 - 2}{x+1}\right) = \frac{1}{x+1}$$

To the second one, just remember $$|x| = \begin{cases} x , \,\, \text{if}\,\, x\geq 0\\-x, \,\,\text{if}\,\,x<0 \end{cases}$$

and take the side limits.

Comment: yea but the left side result is 4/x if i compensate x=0 then this term has no limi because it's equal to 4/0 .. 
so there will be no limit for this question ?

Comment: The limit doesn't exist, that's right.

Comment: ok thanks for your helpful answer ^^

Comment: You're welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac2{x^2-1}=\frac{x+1}{x^2-1}-\frac{2}{x^2-1}=\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}=\frac{(x-1)}{(x-1)(x+1)}=\cdots?$$

Comment: thanks,seems i did a little mistake when i combined the 2 terms

Answer (score 0):

make a change of variable $x = 1 + h, h = x - 1.$  then $$\frac1{x-1}-\frac2{x^2-1} = \frac1h - \frac2{(1+h)^2 - 1} =\frac1h-\frac{2}{2h+h^2}=\frac{1}{(2+h)} \to \frac12$$ as $h \to 0.$

Comment: @user31415, thanks. is  fixed now.